# gensim on EC2: installation issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation, gensim

I am trying to install gensim on EC2 (RedHat - t2-micro) to build a REST API. The overall installation process is really long so I shorten the code to replicate the error I am getting. Here below the shorter version:

- sudo yum update -y (EC2 update)
- sudo yum install nano (nano editor)
- sudo yum -y install gcc-c++ python27-devel atlas-sse3-devel lapack-devel (various Gensim related packages)
- sudo yum -y install httpd (Apache)
- sudo yum install mod_wsgi (WSGI)
- curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py then sudo python2.7 get-pip.py (PIP)
- virtualenv -p python2.7 /tmp/my_app then . /tmp/my_app/bin/activate (virtual env)

With my virtual env setup, I then added numpy, scipy, and gensim:
- pip install -U --force numpy
- pip install -U --force scipy
- pip install -U --force

Now if I add a simple file with the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gensim

def main():
    return "Hello my AVABBBCCCDDDEEE world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and run "python file.py" in the terminal (MACOS), i get the following error:

/tmp/ava_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py:1015: UserWarning: Pattern library is not installed, lemmatization won't be available.
  warnings.warn("Pattern library is not installed, lemmatization won't be available.")
No handlers could be found for logger "gensim.models.doc2vec"

Any idea? The error results in a 500 error in the browser.

Many thanks, Stephane